# parallel in R - function not found - how to export to cluster functions from external libraries

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Just started using `library(parallel),` rewrote my code in terms of `parLapply`, made a cluster `cluster <- makeCluster(cores)`  and loaded the functions I need into the cluster by `clusterExport(cluster, as.vector(lsf.str(.GlobalEnv)))`

However, I have some functions in my pipeline from external packages, i.e. function foo from library(bar).  These don't seem to get exported into the cluster.

For example, I got this error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  8 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "expect_equal"
```

where my function is 'expect_equal' from the testthat package.However I definitely called `library(testthat)` before executing my parallelized pipeline.

So, how do I export these external library functions into my R cluster? Do I need to call these in my parallelized code? That would be a pain to keep track of every library this code depends on...

thanks!

Comment: Yes, your parallelised code should be self-sufficient, which means that you should export the libraries when you start executing your parallelized pipeline. I don't really understand why it would be difficult to know which are the libraries you use... don't you import them in the non-parallelised? Otherwise, you can work with try-errors approach or you can switch to the hammer type `sessionInfo()` to find which are the libraries you have in your environment and export everything...

Comment: `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(testthat))` and yes you do need to load all your libraries in your cluster just like you need to do in your scripts.